# how to write where clause for join table in sqlite and get all contacts where removed = 0

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

I have two tables `contacts` and `transactions`

contacts tables

```
id   name             phone               dateAdded         sync removed
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
"1" "contact 1"     "1234567833"        "1594165922373"     "0"   "0"
"2" "contact 2"     "1212323233"        "1594317627740"     "0"   "0"
"3" "contact 3"     "1213232234"        "1594317638122"     "0"   "0"
"4" "contact 4"     "1213234343"        "1594317644570"     "0"   "0"
"5" "contact 5"     "2324343433"        "1594371283234"     "0"   "0"
```

transactions table

```
id  amount   txDate         contactId    sync   removed
---------------------------------------------------------
"1" "-600"  "1594165927398"   "1"          "0"    "0"
"2" "100"   "15941234567"     "1"          "0"    "1"
```

Query

```
select a.removed, tx.removed, a.id, CASE WHEN sum(tx.amount) IS NULL THEN 0 else sum(tx.amount) END  as amount, a.name, a.phone, a.dateAdded, tx.txDate, tx.contactId from contacts as a left join i_transaction tx on a.id = tx.contactId where a.removed = 0 and tx.removed = 0  group by a.id, tx.contactId order by tx.txDate desc, a.dateAdded desc
```

I want to get all contacts with where a.removed = 0 and tx.removed = 0 (a=contacts, tx = transactions)
but problem is it only give me one result where the contactId have data in  transactions table.

I want every contact which exclude removed =1 rows. if I remove and tx.removed = 0 from query it give me all contacts but it also add 100 amount in sum that I don't want because i want to exclude any row where removed = 1. as you can see row 2 is removed in transactions table.

Comment: Please try format your sql query to more readable format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the condition on TX inside the join condition as follows:

```
SELECT ....
  FROM CONTACTS AS A
  LEFT JOIN I_TRANSACTION TX ON A.ID = TX.CONTACTID AND TX.REMOVED = 0 -- this
 WHERE A.REMOVED = 0
 GROUP BY ..
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want to get all contacts with where a.removed = 0 and tx.removed = 0 (a=contacts, tx = transactions)

Is this what you want?

```
select c.*, t.*
from contacts c join
     transactions t
     on t.contactid = c.id
where c.removed = 0 and t.removed = 0;
```

This returns all contact/transaction pairs where this occurs.

Comment: it giving me only 1 row. my query is same as yours

Comment: I want every contact. what I think is  contacts id column is not present in transactions contactId column  that is why it giving me only one row